# How can I change my search form to bring up product results, not blog results

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search, forms

I'm currently building a wordpress/woocommerce site using a template, and am having issues with the search form & results.

When using the search bar, results come up with the title 'blog', and display as blog results instead of product.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Search.php file:

```
<div class="ps-search">

<div class="ps-search__content">
    <a class="ps-search__close" href="#">
        <span></span>
    </a>

    <form class="ps-form--search-2" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <h3>

            <?php if(class_exists('Woocommerce')):?>

                <?php esc_html_e('Search products...');?>

            <?php else:?>

                <?php esc_html_e('Search posts...');?>  

            <?php endif;?>  

        </h3>

        <div class="form-group">

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Enter keyword here...', 'xuper');?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_search_query());?>">

            <?php if(class_exists('Woocommerce')):?>

                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">

            <?php endif;?>  

            <button type="submit" class="ps-btn ps-btn--black ps-btn--fullwidth btn-search-popup">
                <?php esc_html_e('Search', 'xuper');?>
            </button>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below filter in your function.php file

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'product');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Hope this will help!